# How can I add a business to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What is the name of the circle-dot pointer([image]) on Google Maps?
Also, how does one get a business added to Google Maps?

[image]

Comment: This question is off-topic because it appears to be about adding data to Google Maps through their web interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Question: Google has not published an official legend.

Second question: This is done using Google's ["Places for Business"](https://www.google.com/business/placesforbusiness/) feature.